# Create new schema and copy all object from old schema to new schema without the table data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I want to create a new schema (`NPS`).

I am having existing schema (`public`).

After creating `NPS`, I want to copy all the contents of the `public` schema to the `NPS` schema without the table data.

and the existing `public` sequences must be set to 0 in the `NPS` schema.

Comments and answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use pg_dump command with --schema-only option. Refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: @RamachandraReddy does it flag the sequence counters to 0 in new schema and please update answer with example. Answer will be appreciated

Comment: pg_dump -s > backup.sql. You need to add other arguments as per your need.

Comment: thus it will set the sequences to 0. If yes then how to restore dump to new schema.

Comment: I don't have any idea about your environment, you can't expect a ready to use solution. I would request you to go through the  link  postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html and let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You use `pg_dump -F c -s -n public <yourdatabase>` to get only the object definitions.

Restore the dump to a different database, rename the schema `public` to `nps` (don't use upper case!), set the schema permissions as appropriate and dump it again.

Restore the dump to the original database.

To answer your question if that will reset sequences, a simple experiment will show you that it does:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testseq;

SELECT nextval('testseq');
 nextval 
---------
       1
(1 row)

SELECT nextval('testseq');
 nextval 
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

Then dump and be convinced:

```
pg_dump -n laurenz -t testseq -s test

...
CREATE SEQUENCE laurenz.testseq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE laurenz.testseq OWNER TO laurenz;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: how to copy schema in same database. if we dump in same database then it will set all sequnces to 0

Comment: You cannot copy a schema within the same database.